# vba copy some specific cells when a cell matches value but cells sometime is same column

Tags: vba

I am facing a problem that is when i use if else statement i can copy the value from table and paste to another sheet,

If the value matches that with same column c in table 1 and 2 (same as in the attached example link) it will just copy the table one match value cell to another sheet.

How can i copy the other matches value to another sheet?

### [Please view the example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAUM8.png) and [Expect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anf1t.png) and [This is Problem output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5SZo.png)

actually now my only problem is when i use if else statement to do this it just copy the first condition that that match value like the column c first yellow colored value,and it will not copy the second cells that is colored match value in column c.thanks.

```
enter code here //Sub tab()

Dim a 
Dim b
a = 2


For b = 3 To 25                             

If Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX)'max' = 5 And Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX)'min' = 2 Then

If Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX)'total' > Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX)'max' Or Sheet1.Cells(XX, XX)'TOTAL' < Sheet1.Cells(XX, XX)'min' Then
        Sheet2.Cells(XX,XX) = Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX).Value  
                      ""

 a= a + 1     
    End If

ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(xx, xx)'max' = 10 And Sheet1.Cells(xx,xx)'min' = 7 Then

    If Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX)'total' > Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX)'max' Or Sheet1.Cells(XX, XX)'TOTAL' < Sheet1.Cells(XX, XX)'min' Then
        Sheet2.Cells(XX,XX) = Sheet1.Cells(XX,XX).Value  
                    ""
a= a+ 1    
End If
Next b
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include sample data not as a picture but formatted properly as an insert. Maybe use a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Then insert that table between code tags. Also, include expected output so we can better understand how your stipulated logic is applied. And this appears to be VBA not vb.Net; if so the latter tag can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for updating. You have a third table which isn't even mentioned but you copy values from. And I still can't see what you are matching on that determines what is kept. I have stared at column C but it isn't talking to me. You copy 20,17,25 which doesn't appear in column C of table 1 or 2. Also, "" is not descriptive unless it is the actual cell value.

Comment: my third table are same problem like my first and second table,actually now my only problem is when i use if else statement to do this it just copy the first condition that that match value like the column c first yellow colored value,and it will not copy the second cells that is colored match value in column c.thanks.

Comment: @QHarr  i had reply about.thanks!